# is there a JSON solution to dynamic generate href in html?

Tags: javascript, html, json

I am making an html page that would show dynamic href links that are controlled by JSON.

```
 <a href="https://wa.me/923002546363" target="_blank">open chat</a>
```

I have built the following HTML code that shows mobile numbers on the HTML page. But I couldn't convert that JSON file's mobile numbers into href as shown above. So, when we add a new number, it automatically appears on the front-end as a hyper-link that we can use to open chat.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>WhatsApp Chat Software</title>


<body>
    <div id="myData"></div>
    <script>
        fetch('number.json')
            .then(function (response) {
                return response.json();
            })
            .then(function (data) {
                appendData(data);
            })
            .catch(function (err) {
                console.log('error: ' + err);
            });
        function appendData(data) {
            var mainContainer = document.getElementById("myData");
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                var div = document.createElement("div");
                div.innerHTML = 'Mobile No: ' + data[i].MobileNo
                
                mainContainer.appendChild(div);
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

below is the number.json

```
[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "MobileNo": "923002546363"

    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "MobileNo": "923343676143"

    }
]
```

Comment: You're not creating an `<a>`, you're just creating the `<div>`.

Comment: Thank you. with your solution problem is solved. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `document.createElement('a')` to create an anchor, and set its `href`.

```js
function appendData(data) {
  var mainContainer = document.getElementById("myData");
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    var a = document.createElement('a');
    a.href = `https://wa.me/${data[i].MobileNo}`;
    a.innerText = 'Open chat';
    div.appendChild(a);
    mainContainer.appendChild(div);
  }
}
```